# Hiding & showing markers on event

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

```
google.maps.Marker.prototype.hide = function() 
{
    if (this.div_) 
    {
        this.div_.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
};
google.maps.Marker.prototype.show = function() 
{
    if (this.div_) {
        this.div_.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
};
```

It doesnt cause any error. But it doesnt work while Im using it:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                position: latlng,
                title: 'some title'
            });
```

And now if someone change the zoom I want to trigger hiding marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            marker.hide();
});
```

But it doesnt work. Could someone help me resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to hide a marker use `marker.setMap(null);`

to show again use `marker.setMap(mymap);`

EDIT:

forgot about setvisible. here's a working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/herostwist/v9nmQ/1/

Comment: I tried solution with setVisible method. Maybe I was doing sth wrong, but it simply doesnt work. Could you provide some code which for sure work? Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work if the marker is not on the map (if user has scrolled, for example).

Answer (score 0):

The API already contains such a method: [**`setVisible`**](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker). Either pass `true` or `false`.